How does lsp-mode determine the root of the project?
When I open up a file inside a project(lets say the linux kernel), it seems to open up in much higher level directory than the project is in
Lets say I open: ~/Projects/C/Kernel/linux-6.12.4/include/net/sock.h or whatever and lsp-mode says: clang connected on ~/Projects/C, while both .clangd and compile_commands.json are in ~/Projects/C/Kernel/linux-6.12.4/.
How does lsp-mode try and determine the root of the project? (wrongly) Does it use the first directory where there is .git directory, or just by russian rulete
Also, the settings from the ~/Projects/C/Kernel/linux-6.12.4/.clangd are not being detected by emacs, therefore I cannot configure for it to use the proper clangd settings and its broken.
Now, is it possible to set the lsp-mode some kind of boundary when executing the clangd server, such as creating a file that would make it launch it in the correct directory?

Check https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/c3be413f8545a26ad0334e1dd2b7e65c448d9f22/lsp-mode.el#L5139-L5148


How does lsp-mode try and determine the root of the project? (wrongly) Does it use the first directory where there is .git directory, or just by russian rulete

lsp-mode employs heuristics to determine the root of the project, and being inside a git repo as you pointed out is one of them. Executing lsp for the first time inside a directory that doesn't belong to any root would result in lsp-mode interactively asking you for the root location. Heuristics are not applied blindly by lsp, instead their result is being suggested at the default value, and can be dismissed in preference of another directory.
With that said, heuristics though are just that, heuristics. For me personally "being inside git repo" rule is typically correct, but of course it may mismatch. One example is when you have unpacked a tarball with sources while being inside another repo. Another one is kind of a subproject inside a larger repo.
Now, if you do not see the question when you execute lsp, that means you already imported the project and it resides at ~/Projects/C. I will assume here that it is a project root that you want to keep, but you also want to develop other "subprojects" inside the project.
This is done by executing M-x lsp-workspace-folders-add, and then choosing the path. In your case you chose path to ~/Projects/C/Kernel/linux-6.12.4, and then whenever you execute lsp in any of its subdirectories, the "current dir" for clangd will be set to ~/Projects/C/Kernel/linux-6.12.4 as expected so it will see compile_commands.json and other stuff.
